# How can I display a file browser (just like explorer) in a native win32 app?

Tags: c++, winapi

I don't want an open dialog box.

Something like photo importers do.

Basically I want a always on control/window, that takes the bottom half of the main window, and displays folders just like explorer (just like an open dialog box, except I don't want a dialog box, I want it to be always there, and than double click or drag contents to the main window (at will, it will not close)).

I can't find any info on msdn on how to do that. Perhaps I'm not searching for the correct terms?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is the [IExplorerBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. The linked page contains links to samples for using it.

Comment: You could use spy++ to find out what the control is called.